# MathJax. Math processing error в android app

Tags: android, mathjax

В Андроид приложении подключила mathjax для вывода формул, в итоге все работает. Но по истечении какого - то времени после загрузки страницы с формулами (они отображаются - все хорошо ), вместо формул отображается Math Processing Error. В принципе. не напрягает, но все-таки...